# Export a Json object to a text File

Tags: javascript, json, fwrite, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to write a Json object (JsonExport) and I'd like to write its content into a text file.

I'm using max4live to export data from Audio DAW to Json in order to export to a server, but after that I would like to see the whole Json Object in a text file:

```
 var txtFile = "test.txt";
 var file = new File(txtFile);
 var str = JSON.stringify(JsonExport);


 file.open("write"); // open file with write access
 file.write(str);
 file.close();
```

The compiler runs with no error, but i can not get the text file. I have used as well path to some of my directories and nothing.

Any idea what's happening? Thanks

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055391/writing-data-to-a-local-text-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got it! It worked by changing few parameters like this:

```
   var txtFile = "/tmp/test.txt";
   var file = new File(txtFile,"write");
   var str = JSON.stringify(JsonExport);

   log("opening file...");
   file.open(); 
   log("writing file..");
   file.writeline(str);
   file.close();
```

Path to my directories not allowed, so i had to save it on /tmp directory. 
Thanks to all!

Comment: can we write to txt file using this method if javascript is run on browser?

Answer (score 29):

I know this question already has accepted answer but I think my answer could help someone. So, the problem is to export Json data to a text file. Once you execute the following code, file will be downloaded by the browser.

```
const filename = 'data.json';
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(JsonExport);

let element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(jsonStr));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you have access to an already existing file, just link to it.  You can specify what the downloaded file name will be like this:

```
<a href="path/to/file.txt" download="example.json">
    Download as JSON
</a>
```

If needed, you could also write out the dataURI as well

```
 //Get the file contents
 var txtFile = "test.txt";
 var file = new File(txtFile);
 var str = JSON.stringify(JsonExport);

 //Save the file contents as a DataURI
 var dataUri = 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(str);

 //Write it as the href for the link
 var link = document.getElementById('link').href = dataUri;
```

Then just give the link an ID and a default `href`

```
<a href="#" id="link" download="example.json">
    Download as JSON
</a>
```