# How to write in a text file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, text-files

I want to know how to write strings in a textfile on my machine when I click on a button in my Html page using Javascript... I want an Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox compatibility...

Thanks

Comment: Just imagine what hackers could do if JavaScript had access to your filesystem...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055391/writing-data-to-a-local-text-file-with-javascript

Comment: It seems from a comment that you're using ActiveX. Good luck persuading Mozilla and Google to support it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Comment: what you could do, is to create a virtual file with JavaScript, which would be downloadable like any other file on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. It would be a major security risk if browsers could write anything on the user's filesystem.

Best you could do is create a text file on your server, and serve it for download.

Comment: if I use that code, it's working, but the file goes directly on the desktop... If I change the filename to C:\test\testfile.txt, nothing happend...

var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
var TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0;
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var filename = "testfile.txt";
fso.CreateTextFile(filename);
var fileObj = fso.GetFile(filename);
var ts = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault);
ts.WriteLine("Hello World!");
ts.WriteLine("The quick brown fox");
ts.Close();

Comment: @ThomasJomphe It shouldn't even be possible to write to the client's desktop. That must either be a vulnerability, or the browser realizing it's being served locally. You **cannot** write directly to a client's drive. The best you can do is make use of `LocalStorage`.

Answer (score -3):

There ara some questions like yours here in stackoverflow, try some these links

[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

[How to read and write into file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)

or you can try this [gist example](https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725)

Edit:

The Gist example only works for node.js sorry

Comment: Are you read comments of your gist?