# Write data to a local file by javascript/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm beginner to the JS development.what I want to do is write the data to a file in local storage.

In my application i read a raw data and save it in mongoDB as key value pairs.same time i want to write those data to a file in a local storage.

this code is used to read the read the file line by line.i get structured data in "event" .what i want to do is write those data to a file in  local storage.

```js
 var lines = readDetails.split('\n');

 for(var line = 0; line < lines.length-1; line++){
   var FileContent = "";
  
   var linesSpace = lines[line].split(' ');

   for(var y=3;y <= linesSpace.length-1;y++){
   
      FileContent +=linesSpace[y];
      FileContent += " ";
      
      }
      
     var event = {
          dat: linesSpace[0],
          tim: linesSpace[1],
          details: FileContent,
  
  }; 
 
}
```

if this is not that much clear .please questioned me.

Thanks.

Comment: By local storage do you mean the HTML 5 local storage API or do you want to save it on some file on local disk ?

Comment: you can use localStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify(YOUR DATA));

Comment: @Harry i meant a file on local disk.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055391/writing-data-to-a-local-text-file-with-javascript) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) is the best I've found, super easy to use.